# Swift: Return JSON string from NSURLSession task

Tags: json, string, swift, nsurlsession

I'd like to get token as String type, however the following code returns error as " "String" is not convertible to "Void" ".
Could you tell me what is the problem?
In order to parse JSON, I used [SwiftyJSON](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111)

```
func authentication() -> String {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://~~~/v2/authenticate/api")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var loginID = "my_ID"
    var apiKey = "my_APIKEY"
    var postString:NSString = "login_id=\(loginID)&api_key=\(apiKey)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")


        let json = JSON(data:data)
        if let token = json["auth_token"].stringValue{
            println("\(token)")

            return token ///Error Here
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

※Edited Jan6th 7:50(GMP+9hr)
I edited as following, however I got error as ""Use of unresolved identifier "tokenString".
Please tell me how to solve the problem.

```
func authentication() -> String {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://~~~/v2/authenticate/api")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var loginID = "my_ID"
    var apiKey = "my_APIKEY"
    var postString:NSString = "login_id=\(loginID)&api_key=\(apiKey)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")


        let json = JSON(data:data)
        if let token = json["auth_token"].stringValue{
            println("\(token)")

            tokenString = self.didReceiveAuthToken(token)///Edited 
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return tokenString
}
func didReceiveAuthToken(token : String) ->String{
    return token
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataTaskWithRequest` closure takes a return type of `void`. Your method that returns a string ends immediately after `task.resume()` is executed and does not return anything.

Your basic problem is that you're applying synchronous thinking to an asynchronous task. One easy suggestion is to have `authentication()` return void (ie, nothing), and then make a separate method like `didReceiveAuthToken(token : String)` that is called by your completion handler when the token is received.

Comment: I edited code based on your advice as above, however I cannot get token string outside of authentication function. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Call the method you created, using the token as an argument.

Comment: wouldn't a simple delegate pattern, to call a method and pass back the data to another class be a good solution here also?

Comment: @Woodstock A delegate handler is okay for certain cases, but sometimes it can mess stuff up because data doesn't always come back in the same order it is requested, so you can run into synchronization issues. In this particular case it would probably be fine.